# How to parse file XML by lxml, get element & attribute?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I have a xml description like this:

```
    <Car xmlns="http://example.com/vocab/xml/cars#">
     <dateStarted>{{date_started|escape}}</dateStarted>
     <dateSold>{{date_sold|escape}}</dateSold>
    <name type="{{name_type}}" abbrev="{{name_abbrev}}" value="{{name_value}}" >{{name|escape}}</name>
    <brandName type="{{brand_name_type}}" abbrev="{{brand_name_abbrev}}" value="{{brand_name_value}}" >{{brand_name|escape}}</brandName>
      <maxspeed>
        <value>{{speed_value}}</value>
        <unit type="{{speed_unit_type}}" value="{{speed_unit_value}}" abbrev="{{speed_unit_abbrev}}" />
      </maxspeed>
      <route type="{{route_type}}" value="{{route_value}}" abbrev="{{route_abbrev}}">{{by_route|escape}}</route>
      <power>
        <value>{{strength_value|escape}}</value>
        <unit type="{{strength_unit_type}}" value="{{ strength_unit_value }}" abbrev="{{ strength_unit_abbrev }}" />
      </power>
      <frequency type="{{ frequency_type }}" value="{{frequency_value}}" abbrev="{{ frequency_abbrev }}">{{frequency|escape}}</frequency>  
    </Car>
```

I write a function parse_car using Python, to parse from a string use the above format:

```
    def parse_car(etree):
        NS = "{http://example.com/vocab/xml/cars#}"
        CODES_NS = "{http://example.com/codes/}"


        return {'date_started' : etree.findtext('%sdateStarted' % NS),
        'date_stopped' : etree.findtext('%sdateStopped' % NS),
        'name': etree.findtext('%sname' % NS),
        'brand_name': etree.findtext('%sbrandName' % NS),
        'maxspeed': etree.findtext('%smaxspeed/value' % NS),
        'maxspeed_unit': etree.findtext('%smaxspeed/value' % NS).get('abbrev'),
        'route': etree.findtext('%sroute' % NS),
        'power': etree.findtext('%spower/value' % NS),
        'power_unit': etree.find('%spower/value' % NS).get('abbrev'),
        'frequency': etree.findtext('%sfrequency' % NS) }
```

But I only get a part of result. Here it is: it stop at route:

```
    <Car xmlns="http://example.com/vocab/xml/cars#">
     <dateStarted>2011-02-05</dateStarted>
     <dateStopped>2011-02-13</dateStopped>         
    <name type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="X6" value="BMW X6" >BMW X6</name>
    <brandName type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="BMW" value="BMW" >BMW</brandName>
      <maxspeed>
        <value>250</value>
        <unit type="http://example.com/codes/units#" value="miles" abbrev="mph" />
      </maxspeed>
      <route type="http://...'
```

And here is the expected final result:

```
    <Car xmlns="http://example.com/vocab/xml/cars#">
     <dateStarted>2011-02-05</dateStarted>
     <dateSold>2011-02-13</dateSold>
    <name type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="X6" value="BMW X6" >BMW X6</name>
    <brandName type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="BMW" value="BMW">BMW</brandName>
      <maxspeed>
        <value>250</value>
        <unit type="http://example.com/codes/units#" value="miles" abbrev="mph" />
      </maxspeed>
      <route type="http://example.com/codes/routes#" abbrev="HW" value="Highway" >Highway</route>
      <power>
        <value>{{strength_value|escape}}</value>
        <unit type="http://example.com/codes/units#" value="powerhorse" abbrev="ph" />
      </power>
      <frequency type="http://example.com/codes/frequency#" value="daily" >Daily</frequency>  
    </Car>
```

Could you please give me some advice why it doesn't work? Do I miss some thing here? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: I have just thinking about this ability: it get into a sub-element of speed and it can't get back to one level, so it can't parse the route. Is it correct? If so, how can I get out one level?

Comment: There is no maxspeed in the input, and yet it shows up in the desired final result. Is the posted input incomplete?

Comment: My typo, I copied it from the original one and for got to change it.

Comment: 'maxspeed': etree.findtext('%smaxspeed/value' % NS),
'maxspeed_unit': etree.findtext('%smaxspeed/value' % NS).get('abbrev'),  Is this syntax correct or not?

Comment: Your input includes double curly braces, which makes me think this might be a template for a template engine such as [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). If that is true, the proper way to replace the double curlies with values would be to [use jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/intro/#basic-api-usage).

Comment: `findtext()` returns a string. Strings do not have a `get()` method.

Comment: It turn out that I only need to get the attribute of maxspeed element as I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161530/get-attribute-of-complex-element-using-lxml