# Get attribute of complex element using lxml

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I have a simple file XML like below:

```
    <brandName type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="BMW" value="BMW" />BMW</brandName>
      <maxspeed>
        <value>250</value>
        <unit type="http://example.com/codes/units#" value="miles per hour" abbrev="mph" />
      </maxspeed>
```

I want to parse it using lxml and get the value of it:
With brandName, it just need:

```
    'brand_name'  : m.findtext(NS+'brandName')
```

If I want to get into abbrev attribute of it.

```
    'brand_name'  : m.findtext(NS+'brandName').attrib['abbrev']
```

With maxspeed, i can get the value of maxspeed by:

```
    'maxspeed_value'                  : m.findtext(NS+'maxspeed/value'),
```

or:

```
    'maxspeed_value'                  : m.find(NS+'maxspeed/value').text,
```

Now, I want to get the attribute of unit inside , I have tried a lot of different way but I'm failed. The error most of time is:

```
    'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'
```

Here are several ways I tried and it failed:

```
    'maxspeed_unit'                  : m.find(NS+'maxspeed/value').attrib['abbrev'],
    'maxspeed_unit'                  : (m.find(NS+'maxspeed/value'))get('abbrev'),
```

Could you please give me some hint why it doesn't work?
Thank you very much!

UPDATE XML:

```
    <Car xmlns="http://example.com/vocab/xml/cars#">
     <dateStarted>2011-02-05</dateStarted>
     <dateSold>2011-02-13</dateSold>
    <name type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="X6" value="BMW X6" >BMW X6</name>
    <brandName type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="BMW" value="BMW" />BMW</brandName>
      <maxspeed>
        <value>250</value>
        <unit type="http://example.com/codes/units#" value="miles per hour" abbrev="mph" />
      </maxspeed>
      <route type="http://example.com/codes/routes#" abbrev="HW" value="Highway" >Highway</route>
      <power>
        <value>180</value>
        <unit type="http://example.com/codes/units#" value="powerhorse" abbrev="ph" />
      </power>
      <frequency type="http://example.com/codes/frequency#" value="daily" >Daily</frequency>  
    </Car>
```

Comment: I have just tried another one but it didn't work:
 'maxspeed_unit'  : m.find('.//maxspeed/unit').get('abbrev')

Because I see from here: https://sites.google.com/site/bmaupinwiki/home/programming/python/python-xml-lxml
I think that the current element is maxspeed/value, so it can't find maxspeed/unit inside it. But I don't know how to get it back one level, so I tried .//, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .find method on an lxml Element will only search the direct sub-children of that element. so for example in this xml:

```
<root>
    <brandName type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="BMW" value="BMW">BMW</brandName>
    <maxspeed>
        <value>250</value>
        <unit type="http://example.com/codes/units#" value="miles per hour" abbrev="mph" />
    </maxspeed>
</root>
```

You can use the root Elements .find method to locate the brandname element, or the maxspeed element, but the search will not traverse inside these inner elements.

So you could for example do something like this:

```
root.find('maxspeed').find('unit') #returns the unit Element
```

From this returned element you can access the attributes.

If you'd like to search through all the elements within an XML doc, you can use the .iter() method. So for the previous example you could say:

```
for element in root.iter(tag='unit'):
    print element #This would print all the unit elements in the document.
```

**EDIT:** Here is a small fully functional example using the xml you provided:

```
import lxml.etree
from StringIO import StringIO

def ns_join(element, tag, namespace=None):
    '''Joins the namespace and tag together, and
    returns the fully qualified name.
    @param element - The lxml.etree._Element you're searching
    @param tag - The tag you're joining
    @param namespace - (optional) The Namespace shortname default is None'''

    return '{%s}%s' % (element.nsmap[namespace], tag)

def parse_car(element):
    '''Parse a car element, This will return a dictionary containing
    brand_name, maxspeed_value, and maxspeed_unit'''

    maxspeed = element.find(ns_join(element,'maxspeed'))
    return { 
        'brand_name' : element.findtext(ns_join(element,'brandName')), 
        'maxspeed_value' : maxspeed.findtext(ns_join(maxspeed,'value')), 
        'maxspeed_unit' : maxspeed.find(ns_join(maxspeed, 'unit')).attrib['abbrev']
        }

#Create the StringIO object to feed to the parser.
XML = StringIO('''
<Reports>
    <Car xmlns="http://example.com/vocab/xml/cars#">
        <dateStarted>2011-02-05</dateStarted>
        <dateSold>2011-02-13</dateSold>
        <name type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="X6" value="BMW X6" >BMW X6</name>
        <brandName type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="BMW" value="BMW" >BMW</brandName>
        <maxspeed>
            <value>250</value>
            <unit type="http://example.com/codes/units#" value="miles per hour" abbrev="mph" />
        </maxspeed>
        <route type="http://example.com/codes/routes#" abbrev="HW" value="Highway" >Highway</route>
        <power>
            <value>180</value>
            <unit type="http://example.com/codes/units#" value="powerhorse" abbrev="ph" />
        </power>
        <frequency type="http://example.com/codes/frequency#" value="daily" >Daily</frequency>  
    </Car>
</Reports>
''')

#Get the root element object of the xml
car_root_element = lxml.etree.parse(XML).getroot()

# For each 'Car' tag in the root element,
# we want to parse it and save the list as cars
cars = [ parse_car(element) 
    for element in car_root_element.iter() if element.tag.endswith('Car')]

print cars
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I see this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
The code:
car.append({         
          'brand_name' : m.findtext(NS+'brandName'),
          'maxspeed'   : m.findtext(NS+'dose/value')
          'maxspeed_value': m.find('dose').find('value').attrib['abbrev'],
      }) Can I do it on 1 line of code only?

Comment: If the element that you are searching for does not exist, .find() will return None. In the example you provided are you certain that the 'dose' element exists?

Comment: Sorry, the correct code is: car.append({ 'brand_name' : m.findtext(NS+'brandName'), 'maxspeed' : m.findtext(NS+'maxspeed/value') 'maxspeed_value': m.find('maxspeed').find('value').attrib['abbrev'], )

Comment: 'maxspeed_unit': m.find('maxspeed').find('unit').attrib['abbrev'], didn't work.

Comment: ''maxspeed_unit': ((m.find(''maxspeed')).find('unit')).attrib['value'], didn't work too!

Comment: Well just from what I can see... In the example we are playing with, The 'value' tag, does not contain an 'abbrev' attribute, and so you would get a KeyError trying to access it. I guess I am not exactly sure what your question is now?

Comment: Well, I just want to get the value of attribute type, value, abbrev inside the element <unit of maxspeed

Comment: Is m your XML's root element? What is the error that you are getting now?

Comment: NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Here is about m:
reports = et.findall('Report')
    for report in reports:
      item = report[1]
      m = item[0]

Comment: So m is not the root element of document, inside document has a lot of Report elements and inside each Report element it has Car element.

Comment: It sounds like you are getting back None when you run m.find('maxspeed'). Are you certain that m is the direct parent element of 'maxspeed'? Can you post the actual XML file that you are using?

Comment: There is an error in the XML that you just posted. <brandName type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="BMW" value="BMW" />BMW</brandName> -- should read -- <brandName type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="BMW" value="BMW" >BMW</brandName>  Not sure if that would cause this problem, but it is worth checking.

Comment: Error still the same, I'm not sure what is wrong with xml file

Comment: I see the error! I changed it and it still the same. So it may not be this error.

Comment: It is also looking for a namespace here. In this case you can access the 'Car' namespace using m.nsmap[None]. So for example you could say: 
m.find('{%s}maxspeed' % m.nsmap[None]). Edit: Fixed the variable name.

Comment: I tried  m.find('{%s}maxspeed' % NS).find('{%s}unit' % NS).attrib['value'], but It seem not work!

Comment: Wait! I changed it to m.find('%smaxspeed' % NS).find('%sunit' % NS).attrib['%svalue' % NS], . The Error now is 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'. May bet we get it very soon!

Comment: What is your namespace variable equal to? It should be 'http://example.com/vocab/xml/cars#'.

Comment: With m.find('%smaxspeed' % NS).find('%sunit' % NS).attrib['value'], . Error is the same: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'.

Comment: If you NS variable already contains the brackets you should try: m.find('%smaxspeed' % NS).find('%sunit' % NS).attrib['value']

Comment: Yes. And only the type attribute has namespace, value and abbrev does not have namespace.

Comment: NS = '{http://'example.com/vocab/xml/cars#}'
And m.find('%smaxspeed' % NS).find('%sunit' % NS).attrib['abbrev'], but still not work!

Comment: Try this one: m.find('{%s}maxspeed' % m.nsmap[None]).find('{%s}unit' % m.nsmap[None]).attrib['value'] and see if that works.

Comment: _ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'nsmap'

Comment: How are you parsing your XML? To get the m object originally, can you post that code?

Comment: Here is the parse function: def parse_car(etree):

return { 'brand_name'    : etree.findtext('%sbrandName' % NS),
'maxspeed_value'          : etree.findtext('%smaxspeed/value' % NS),
'maxspeed_unit'     : etree.find('maxspeed').find('unit').attrib['abbrev'], }

Comment: But in order to actually get the etree. Are you calling a function like etree = lxml.etree.parse('path/to/file.xml').getroot() ?

Comment: I hard code car_xml =''' content here '''.encode(). I do like this before and I can receive name and value of it.

Comment: Here is the original of question that I think can describe it more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155855/how-to-parse-file-xml-by-lxml-get-element-attribute

Comment: Can you try running from StringIO import StringIO; car_xml = StringIO(''' content here '''); car = lxml.etree.parse(car_xml).getroot(); parse_car(car); That should work.

Comment: I do as you said and receive: 'module' object is not callable at StringIO('''Content here''');

Comment: Make sure you use `from StringIO import StringIO`

Comment: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Try `StringIO.StringIO(''' content here ''')`

Comment: It has another error: 'module' object has no attribute 'etree'. i have allready import xml.etree

Comment: Matt, I think that i'm getting lost.Maybe I should look at the code more thoroughly and come back later with more clear understanding. Thank you very much for your time and your effort you have spend trying to solve the problem with me. Sure that I will contact you or your company when I need your help on projects related to Android phone apps, it will come soon after I finish this project. I'm not a programmer, I'm just trying to make the demo.

Comment: Glad to see that you guys are patiently working through this issue, but please consider taking extended discussions to [chat] so as not to clog up the pipes here ;) Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, I am sorry that I wasn't able to help you more. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
import lxml.etree as ET
content='''
<Car xmlns="http://example.com/vocab/xml/cars#">
 <brandName type="http://example.com/codes/bmw#" abbrev="BMW" value="BMW" >BMW</brandName>
   <maxspeed>
     <value>250</value>
     <unit type="http://example.com/codes/units#" value="miles per hour" abbrev="mph" />
   </maxspeed>
 </Car>
'''

doc=ET.fromstring(content)
NS = 'http://example.com/vocab/xml/cars#'
# print(ET.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True))
for x in doc.xpath('//ns:maxspeed/ns:unit/@abbrev',namespaces={'ns': NS}):
    print(x)
```

yields

```
mph
```

Comment: I changed it to:
'maxspeed_unit'       : m.xpath('//ns:maxspeed/ns:unit/@abbrev',namespaces={'ns': NS}) ,
There is no error with this one but it has another error with brand_name:
 'brand_name'  : m.findtext(NS+'brandName'),
It's so strange. I don't know why. Do you have any guest?

Comment: Error is the same: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'

Comment: I restart no error like above but it has this error: _ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'xpath'